# Do elders help the villain in a non-showdown fight round?

Tags: a-touch-of-evil

I'm having a Fight Round with the Villain outside of a Showdown ([Deadly Encounter](http://flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=Card%3aDeadly_Encounter) Mystery card) and an Evil Elder has joined him already (it's cooperative mode and the elder has been investigated and revealed to be evil).

Since Evil Elders helping the Villain are only mentioned in the Showdown section and this is specifically *not* a Showdown, my thinking is that the elder should not provide the usual +1 Combat and +1 Wound... but is that really the case in cooperative mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Villain gets +1 Combat skill during the single Fight Round**

Actually, [the rules](http://www.flyingfrog.net/atouchofevil/pdf%5CATOE_Rulebook_Web.pdf) do mention Evil Elders outside the Showdown section. Specifically, on page 15.

> **Evil Elders** - When a Town Elder is shown to be evil, they cease to be a Town Elder and instead become an Evil Elder. The card is flipped over, any Secrets they had are discarded, and they are repositioned next to the Villain’s Record Sheet. **Evil Elders give the Villain +1 Combat** and have one Wound.

This bonus is applied to the Villain's Combat, regardless of whether this is a Showdown fight or not.

> **Fighting the Villain** - Occasionally a hero will have to engage in a single Fight Round with the Villain due to a **Mystery Card or Minion Chart result**. These Fights are NOT considered a Showdown and consequently, the Villain cannot actually be hurt. In these cases, a single Fight Round should be played out between the Hero and the Villain as described above (**the Villain rolls Fight Dice equal to its Combat**).

Comment: An interesting question to me is, does [Deadly Encounter](http://flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=Card%3aDeadly_Encounter) with the Villain allow you to kill any Evil Elders that are with the Villain? The Deadly Encounter rules specifically prevent wounding the Villain, and **Targeting Evil Elders** is only applicable during a Showdown fight. It appears that you cannot wound an Evil Elder (since you cannot target them), but an FAQ clarifying the issue would be nice.

Comment: This actually makes much sense in retrospect. I did miss the Elder bit outside the Showdown section for this topic. Also, interesting secondary question! As you say, though, no wounding should be possible, so I'm going to guess the intent is not to harm _anyone_ on the Villain side during these fights.